# Sending Map from PC to Archos 43 using Chrome to Phone?

Tags: archos-gen8, google-chrome-to-phone

Has anyone used this feature successfully? ([C2DM feature explanation here - warning, it is a technical document](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#push))  As a user, how do you do it?

The only app that I can find that looks like it does this is [Chrome to Phone](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/).
Given the name, is the phone function crucial to pushing a Map to your Android device?

I'm looking to send directions from my PC to my Archos 43 that is paired up with a Bluetooth GPS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome to phone is a great app.  It's one of my most used apps.  Install Chrome to Phone from [App Brain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/google-chrome-to-phone/com.google.android.apps.chrometophone) or the Android market.  Next install the [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oadboiipflhobonjjffjbfekfjcgkhco).  Finally find the directions on Google Maps and click the chrome to phone button.  This will open up either the web page, Google maps, or Google Navigation (can't remember) on your device assuming your device is connected to the internet.

However, since this is not a phone I suspect you won't have an internet connection while you are driving which could be a problem if you are trying to use Google Maps/Navigation.

Comment: The latest version of maps will download all the data needed for your directions so you dont have to have a data connection. There is also a plugin for firefox if you use that browser. Chrome to phone also requires android 2.2 or later, but there are others that support android 2.1

Comment: Yes, it does require Android 2.2.  Good point, I forgot that maps can download all of the data for directions now.  @Ryan Conrad Do you have links for the others that support android 2.1?